# shiny arules htmlwidget graph only populates in Viewer

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, arules

I'm trying to create a shiny app for visualizing association rules. Its running fine except the graph plot keeps getting populated in the R Studio Viewer instead of within the Shiny App. Please Help!. Code below (am running R v 3.4.2)

```
ui<-fluidPage(
titlePanel("test"),
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
radioButtons("hier", "Hierarchy:", c("DEPT", "SUB_DEPT", "CLASS")),      
selectInput("period",label = em("Period"), c("P1","P2"),selected = 'P1'),      
sliderInput("n_rules", "No. of rules:",min = 0, max = 100, value = 10, 
step = 10)
),
mainPanel(plotlyOutput("network_graph"))
)
)
server <- function(input, output){
output$network_graph <- renderPlotly({    
if (input$hier == 'DEPT' & input$period == 'P1') {
print(
(
plot(head(sort(DEPT_P1_All_Customers),input$n_rules), engine = 
"htmlwidget", method = "graph", height = "800px")
))
}
})
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I do not use Ploty but it the docs it uses `plot_ly` instead of `plot`, maybe that will help? Also I am not understanding why you are using the `print` function inside your `renderPlotly`.

Comment: tried 2 changes:
1. Removed the print function
2. Used  plotOutput and renderPlot instead.
 Both giving me same results. The graph is populated in the Viewer instead of within the Shiny app.

plot_ly needs a dataframe - it doesn't recognize the arules data

Comment: The problem seems to be because of the engine="htmlwidget". if I use engine = "default", the plot is rendering correctly within the Shiny app..  But the htmlwidget plot is so much better and interactive which i want to use.

Answer (score 1):

The method "graph" returns a htmlwidget from visNetwork, so you need to use `renderVisNetwork()` instead of `renderPlotly()` in shiny.

Answer (score 0):

For "graph" method change your input and output, as:

`plotlyOutput("network_graph")` to `visNetworkOutput("network_graph")`
and `renderPlotly` to `renderVisNetwork`.